# moderation of "duplicate post"

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I recently asked a question that was, within minutes, flagged by a user with lots of points as an "exact duplicate" of a question that it was not at all an exact duplicate of. Views (and, of course answers) dropped immediately. Can't this be moderated?

Comment: -3 in an hour. Am I asking incorrectly? Is this the wrong place? Is it a "bad" question? If so, how?

Comment: Downvotes on Meta often indicate disagreement with the premise of your question and/or feature-request (i.e., "not useful"). In this case, you are implicitly criticizing the ability of users to close questions as duplicates, which is an *essential* feature of this website and is *not* going to be changed. Downvotes are the community's way of expressing its opposition without requiring a bunch of noisy comments. Beyond that, it's quite unclear exactly what feature you are proposing. What should be "moderated"? Because this doesn't seem to be a feature request at all, I've retagged it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sorta already is. It takes *five* 3K users, or you, or a ♦ moderator, or a gold badge holder, to make an "official" decree that it's a duplicate. They're reviewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close), with inattentive reviewers typically barred from it.

Don't like it? At 250 rep you got one (1) vote to reopen it. Use it and we'll review it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen). 4 others, or one mjölnr, can undo it.

Note that "duplicate" does not mean "verbatim copy". It means "someone else had better search tools including but not limited to their own memory".

See [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: You don't need 250 rep to enqueue a post for reopen-review. All you need to do is edit it. Surprisingly effective when you are unable to find the answer to your question in a proposed duplicate.